# Two "the_excerpt" questions

Tags: images, excerpt

In case there's more than one function the exact one is:

php the_excerpt();

I want to decrease the character length to X amount and I want to remove the [...] and replace it with an image that users can click to take them to the article.  How do I accomplish this (preferably without plugins)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to hook into two WordPress filters.

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_length

```
function custom_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '[.....]';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'custom_excerpt_more' );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_more